# Spectral gap of tempered distributions

Tags: fourier-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, schwartz-distributions

Hi,
Let $\Lambda\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an infinite discrete set of finite density (for simplicity one may take the density equals 1) and $\delta_{\lambda}$
is a unit mass located at the point $\lambda\in\Lambda$. Define the
tempered distribution $\delta_{\Lambda}=\underset{\lambda\in\Lambda}{\sum}\delta_{\lambda}$.
It is known that if there exists a finite set $\Sigma$
such that for every two successive elements of $\Lambda$, $\lambda,\mu$
we have $\lambda-\mu\in\Sigma$ and $\delta_{\Lambda}$ has a spectral
gap then $\Lambda$ must be periodic, i.e. a finite union of copies
of a translated lattice.

I am trying to understand if I can drop the condition of having a
finite set of differences. In other words I am trying to construct
a set $\Lambda$ so that $\delta_{\Lambda}$ will have a spectral
gap but $\Lambda$ will have an infinite set of differences. Obviously
for periodicity of $\Lambda$ I cannot drop this condition altogether
because $\Lambda$ cannot be periodic if its set of differences is
inifinite, but constructing such a distribution will show that the two conditions are separate.
And in a more general tone, How can one get intuition regarding whether a tempered distribution of the kind $\delta_{\Lambda}$ has a spectral gap at all?

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you exactly mean by Spectral gap?

Comment: I believe he is referring to the recent result of Alex Iosevich, Mihail N. Kolountzakis ``Periodicity of the spectrum in dimension one'' http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.5689 where they prove such a result. In the context of that paper `spectral gap' would mean the existence of a > 0 such that supp (\widehat{\delta_\Lambda}) \cap (0,a) = \phi .


Comment: see equation 10 page 6 of the above mentioned paper. 

Comment: That is exactly what I meant.